# How do I tell figwheel to start and connect to Google Chrome instead of Firefox?

Tags: configuration, figwheel

I'm taking some baby steps with *[figwheel](https://figwheel.org/tutorial)*.

When I fire up the [tutorial application](https://figwheel.org/tutorial.html), it starts *firefox*, which then connects back to the *figwheel* process to get code to run on its JavaScript engine. If *firefox* is already running, a new tab is opened and the connection proceeds likewise. *Figwheel* probably just executes the [`firefox` command](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments) with appropriate options. Or maybe it is using [xdg-open](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251054/how-does-the-xdg-open-command-know-which-application-to-use-to-open-a-file).

The system is a Fedora Linux with KDE. Interestingly a "default browser" is not currently configured (how to configure the default browser is described in these [KDE help pages](https://userbase.kde.org/System_Settings/Default_Applications)): the application to start is selected based on URL contents. So I am not sure why *figwheel* selects *firefox* instead of *Google Chrome*, also installed.

[image: Web Browser is selected based on this config]

Now, for testing purposes I sometimes want `figwheeel` to use a `Google Chrome`  process instead. Is there a way to do that?

There seems to be no [option regarding this](https://figwheel.org/config-options).

Answer (score 0):

You can use figwheel's [:launch-js](https://github.com/bhauman/figwheel-main/blob/master/docs/config-options.md#launch-js) option to define what action should be taken for example:

`:launch-js ["chrome" "--repl" :open-url]`